# Android app licensing check

Tags: android, android-lvl

I have an app currently on the Android market. I am updating the app to add Android Licensing. I Basically took the example from Google Android and added it to my app. I changed the public key to mine. I added my email address to the licensing exclusion list. I am running my app on an android device and it is saying the app is not licensed.

How do i fix this?

Are there any good tutorials on android app licensing someone has came across?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your permission on your publisher account it's wrong.
Add your e-mail account test and check the Test Response menu. Change to LICENSED.